# Cypress - Jenkins - Setting environmental variable in the npm run script does not seem to be accessible in cypress files

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, cypress

I have a cypress pipeline setup in Jenkins. When I run my test suite locally it is getting the environmental variables that are in the startup script. But it is failing in Jenkins.
Here is the startup script:

```
"cy:run:tst":"cypress run  --env ENV=staging"
```

This is used to set the URLs for the development environment I need to test (staging, prod, etc).

Am I barking up the wrong tree? Thanks

I tried adding a build variable in the Groovy pipeline script, but I don't think that is something that can be passed to the test file.

I was expecting that since everything else runs fine in the build process and run script that the variables set in my script in package.json would still work in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely there is an extra space before --env. Jenkins does not like that. No issues running it outside of Jenkins. Maybe this will help save somebody the better part of a day figuring out the issue!